# AR(1) coefficients are too high

Tags: r, regression, time-series, autoregressive

I am fitting an AR(1) model and the results I'm getting are too high and don't make sense. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, can someone clear this up?

```
data <- c(0.1287426, 0.1447894, 0.1541330, 0.1481999, 0.1348838, 0.1165681, 0.1140563, 0.1179652, 0.1404826, 0.1418325)
model <- arima(data, c(1,0,0))
model$coef

AR1 = .5582418
Intercept = .1343918
```

This seems to be saying that the model is

$$
 X_t = 0.134 + .558X_{t-1}
$$

which fits values closer to .2, much higher than any values in my series. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
My residuals are shown below

```
-0.004686990  0.013551235  0.013936841  0.002787753 -0.007216242 -0.018098339 -0.010385551 -0.005074459  0.015260830  0.004040577
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way arima function works in R can be confusing. The resulting model is not the one that you stated. It's actually
$$(X_t-0.134) = 0.558(X_{t−1} - 0.134) + e_t$$

So your prediction of the next value is

$0.1343918 + 0.5582418(0.1418325 - 0.1343918) = 0.1385455$

which is equal to what you get from

```
predict(model)$pred
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Is there a way I can specify the model as I originally stated? My goal is to calculate the mean-reverting level of AR(1)

Comment: you can rearrange terms to get the right intercept: in this case, 0.05936867

Comment: I rearranged the terms and got B0(1-B1) = .132(1-.558) = .0592 is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe nothing.  You have shown what the intercept and coefficient for the first term are, but you didn't show what the fit was.  You've asked ARIMA to generate an output - and it's generated it.  It doesn't mean it's a good fit.  Maybe an AR1 model isn't the right choice.

Comment: I've posted the residuals